# Why is $E(X_t|B_t)=\frac{E(X_tB_t)}{E(B_t^2)}B_t$?

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

> Why is $E(X_t|B_t)=\frac{E(X_tB_t)}{E(B_t^2)}B_t$ ? Does this always hold

In an exercise I have to show that $E(X_t|B_t)\neq X_t$, where $X_t=\int_0^t B_s ds$, I think the definition of $X_t$ does not play a big role here, or not ?

Comment: Is $\{B_t\}$ brownian motion? Are you sure is "$E[X_t|B_t]\neq X_t$". (all indexes $t$)?

Comment: @Justpassingby sorry fixed

Comment: If $X_t$ is any process independent of Brownian motion then the right hand side is identically zero but the left hand side is the expectation of $X_t$ which can be nonzero. So you need to use the definition or at least some specific property of $X_t.$

Comment: Indeed this is quite specific to the definition of $X_t$. To solve the exercise, (prove and) use that $E(B_tB_s)=s$ and $E(B_s\mid B_t)=(s/t)B_t$, for every $s$ in $(0,t)$.

Comment: Can you use Ito's Formula?